# Is there an efficient way to identify in which run-time generated room a character is, in a non-grid 3D environment? How?

Tags: c#, 3d, geometry, geolocation

Here is what I am trying to implement. I wrote a script that allows the player to place walls during run-time, in non grid-based 3D environment (walls can be diagonal with rotation increasing/decreasing in amounts of 10 degrees). Like the figure below shows, since wall can form different angles, rooms might end up having both convex and concave angles:

[image]

What I have been looking for, without success so far, is a way to detect in which room a given character is, according to its position. Of course, if that was a grid-based setting, I could only pass an ID for each cell and then retrieve the ID of the cell where the given character stands. However, that being a non-grid setting and with irregular rooms that have shapes unknown in advance, how could I accomplish that in an efficient way?

Many thanks.

EDIT:
Although it is a 3D environment, the problem may be treated as a 2D one since height is not a concern here.

Comment: Is it ok to drop the z coordinate and treat it as a 2D problem? If so point in polygon is straight forward.

Comment: Also don't see a figure showing up.

Comment: Do you know which walls form a which room? (= do you know the polygon "shape" of each room?)

Comment: Do you have constraints when the rooms are built that they have distinct doors or portals between them?

Comment: Sorry for the figure, now it's showing up. So, @Steven, good point: it is totally ok to treat as a 2D problem. I will even edit to make that mention. Also, the only constrains about doors is that each room has to have at least one door. The rest is unconstrained.

Comment: @wondra although I didn't save that information, I guess could do that by modifying my code a bit (i.e. save the vertices of each corner of each room).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest thing would be to solve it as a 2 dimensional problem. Further, if the constraints are such that each room must be 'closed' then it turns into a point-in-polygon problem, which is easy to solve - essentially a test is performed whereby a segment from the point to some infinite distance is tested against each segment of the polygon. If the number of times the ray crosses segments is odd, the point is inside the polygon. If it is even, the point is outside the polygon. There's already an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test

As noted by Wondra's comment & answer, it may be more bullet proof to use the signed winding number method instead, which handles self intersecting polygons and polygons with whole inside them. There is a C++ implementation is found here: http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html

You just need to track the polygon's vertices as the room is created for this to work.

The other thing you'll want to do is to take each room's minimum and maximum points to create an axis aligned bounding box. Prior to testing a room's polygon, test if the player's point is inside the bounding box. If it is not, then there is no point doing further tests for that room. Point-in-AABB 2D is very fast - check if Point.x is  >= AABB.min.x and Point.X <= AABB.max.x, and the same for point.Y. This will greatly increase the performance of your search.

Finally, if you have a *lot* of rooms, you will want to organize your AABBs into a spatial structure to speed that up even more - either a grid, quad-tree or balanced AABB tree (look at Box2D's broadphase for this one - dynamic bounding volume).

As Loren Pechtel outlined in his comment, the grid would store a linked list in each cell of the rooms that overlap the cell. Then you could use the player's position to lookup the cell, which would then have a linked list of the rooms to test. When in the middle of a room you would have only one item in the grid-cell's list. This could be the fastest approach for spatial partitioning if the balance of grid size and room size is correct.

Good luck

Comment: Great idea to combine both spatial partitioning and point in polygon +1. I would like to point out that crossing number cannot handle some convex polygons(self-intersecting to be more precise, but that probably will not be issue here), winding number handles all of them and it is as fast as cn.

Comment: @wondra You are correct - I assumed crossing number would be enough - but you are right a more aggressively testing might be worth the effort since the content is user created.

Comment: Since the problem space is rooms a self-intersecting polygon makes no sense.  You can't put a wall inside a wall--if it's permitted at all it should divide the space into multiple rooms instead of permitting a convex, self-intersecting polygon.

Comment: Another way of organizing rooms for fast searching:  Lay a grid over your space.  Each grid cell has a linked list of the rooms that appear within that grid cell, you only need to test a point against the rooms in it's grid cell.  This is pretty close to O(1), rather than the O(log n) of trees.

Comment: Great answer, @Steven! That's a nice idea. I will give it a try tomorrow, using the winding method. I specially like the spatial partitioning idea and quick AABB check. About the later, what if all the building is Y-rotated? I though of the following. Since the whole problem can be boiled down to 2D as you've asked before, wouldn't it be simpler to transform the character position and the position of the vertices of rooms-polygons to a local space (let's say of the yellow object representing the whole building floor) and then do the check you suggest (char.x >= min.x && char.x <= max.x)?

Comment: @wondra my thought was similar to that of Loren Pechtel: how a self-intersecting can be possible without generating a whole new room? Maybe in the case of an unfinished wall dragged not up to connect other wall? I ask that out of curiosity, since if winding number runs in the same or time complexity as cn, there is no reason not to go with winding.

Comment: @LorenPechtel About the "over space grid" that would run lose to O(1), what you are aguing is that from the spatial partitioning suggested by Steven, a grid-hierarchical approach would be more performant than quad-trees and similar?

Comment: @LorenPechtel That's why I suggested crossing-number solution at first, but I don't know the details of the room building - maybe you can put 'columns' inside rooms? Regardless, if the more robust solution runs at the same speed as a simple crossing-number, it might be worth the effort.

Comment: @MAnd - I'm not clear on what you mean Y-rotated? But yes you can do everything in a room local space if you have the vertices there. The AABB test would want to be in world space to remove the need for a transform into local space.

Comment: @LorenPechtel regarding a grid of linked cells - exactly what I meant by 'grid' - it can be a good idea if the grid density and room density have a ratio that makes the memory consumption work out. If the grid is 5 meter units and the rooms range in size from 10 square meters to 1000 square meters it's a lot of memory in the grid, but if the ratio is reasonable it would be a good solution.

Comment: @Steven I considered it possible that's what you meant but since it wasn't clear I figured I ought to spell it out.  And you would choose your grid size to be reasonable given the expected layout--vast numbers of cells with one room would be wasteful of memory for no real gain.

Comment: In Steven's link, look at the highly-voted but not accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2922778/1130520 It's really just the crossing number algorithm written extremely efficiently, robustly (if you consider the space created by an odd number of self-intersections a hole, as most lasso selection tools do), and with no concern for the winding order of the edges given to it. And it's only 7 lines of code.

Comment: @Jibb Smart if I am not mistaken, it is basically the same as I linked as "implentation", in the link they additionally show how was it derived and explain why it works. Instead of flipping bool it in/decrements integer, that gives you winding numbers so you can get more information where the point lies(e.g. 2 for twice inside = self-intersection). MAnd: I cannot imagine situation where self-intersection (pillar maybe? see example in mentioned link) would be required, but I just wanted to point out there is as fast and as simple solution which is also more robust.

Comment: @wondra - Yes, you're right, it's basically the same, though it's arguable either way whether winding or counting gives a preferable definition of "inside" vs "outside" for the purposes in which it'll be used. That difference should be inconsequential to MAnd's needs here :)

Comment: @wondra I think a pilllar would be more like a hole in the polygon, but thanks for the quite helpful insights. Anyway I will go for the winding algorithm (Jibb Smart: that link has a very elegant implementation, btw) with spatial partitioning based on hierarchical grids.

Comment: @Steven sorry for the confusion. By Y-rotated I was only meaning the case where the whole building is rotated in the vertical (height) axis. But rotation is going to end up being irrelevant since I will probably do the checks with local positions instead of AABB

Comment: In fact the grid spatial partitioning worked like a charm, and paired with the initial check for the max.x, min.x, etc, speed ceased to be a concern at all. That's why the accepted answer goes to Steven, although I have to thanks @wondra a ton for pointing the winding algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

To test whether a [point lies inside of polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) you have some options, best known crossing number algorithm or more "stable" winding algorithm(there is pretty fast [implementation](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html) too).
Alternatively, you can also use some of [spatial partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) algorithms too, most notably [BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)-type. While spatial partitioning will probably offer superior query performance, it will require dynamic updating structure(if rooms can be changed later) - there are dynamic variations of those algorithms, but it will be *significantly* harder to implement.

Comment: That was awesome that you brought the winding approach. Thanks! I will give it a try.